# helm check if key exist and then evaluate if it's value is true on single line condition

Tags: helm, kubernetes-helm

"helm check if key exist and then evaluate if it's value is true on single line condition"
In Helm version 3.10 will the following condition below work as intended or I can achieve it in some other way?

```
{{- if and (hasKey .Values.enableJsConfigMap) (eq .Values.enableJsConfigMap.enabled true) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

This wouldn't work. The second condition will be evaluated regardless of the first. So if the key is not defined there will be an error.
Use `default` instead:

```
{{- if eq (default .Values.enableJsConfigMap false) true }}
# Do something if enableJsConfigMap exists and its value is true
{{- end }}
```